# Persistence Exception when using pojo binding in play framework controller

Tags: playframework

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class Client extends Model{
   public String email;
   public String password;
}
```

I have the following controller :

```
public static void  clientSignUp(models.Client client)
{
     info("Client email" + client.email);
     info("Client password" + client.password);
     client.create();
}
```

When this controller is called, the two logs print out correctly.  But the client.create line errors with this hibernate exception:

```
  PersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: 
  could not get a field value by reflection getter of models.Client.email
```

However, when i change the code slightly to :

```
   public static void  clientSignUp(models.Client client)
   {
    models.Client client2  = new Client();
    client2.email= client.email;
    client2.password = client.password;
    client2.create();
   }
```

It works. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

I may be be a few months late to answer this, but I ran into a similar issue and was able to fix it. To get the context right, here was my environment:

1. I was initializing a model instance in a Bootstrap `Job`.
2. I was in DEV mode, hence was using an in-memory database (`db=mem`)

I tried all of the above options (`.create()`, `.save()`, `.merge()`) - none of it worked for me. Nor did an application re-start.

Finally, what did the trick was clearing the `/tmp` directory and a restart of the app.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change `client.create();` in your first version to `client.save();` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug going on here.
I solved a similar problem (got the same exception - in my case: user.email) by calling .merge() instead of .save()

Afterwards I can actually remove merge() and use save(), which is pretty wierd (even after a server restart).
Something must be cached.

So try client.merge()